# Symfony test entity

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have entity service and I create controller and action get, create, edit and deleted. I look for test and I don't know why I have error? I can enter for this rout and have data, and work fine, but if create client and get status code have 302

But when I comment in security.yml

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

test passed almost all only in the late fall

How to create client with **ROLE_ADMIN** ??
and this test

```
 public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    // Create a new client to browse the application
    $client = static::createClient();

    // Create a new entry in the database
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/services/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /admin/services/");
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Create a new entry')->link());

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_services[services]'  => 'Test',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check data in the show view
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('td:contains("Test")')->count(), 'Missing element td:contains("Test")');

    // Edit the entity
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Update')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_services[services]'  => 'Foo',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check the element contains an attribute with value equals "Foo"
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('[value="Foo"]')->count(), 'Missing element [value="Foo"]');

    // Delete the entity
    $client->submit($crawler->selectButton('Delete')->form());
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check the entity has been delete on the list
    // **this is 51 line**
    $this->assertNotRegExp('/Foo/', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

and I have

```
' does not match PCRE pattern "/Foo/".

  /home/ivan/host/test/src/Artel/AdminBundle/Tests/Controller/ServicesControllerTest.php:51
```

where error ?

**UPDATE**

change

```
class ServicesControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
private $client = null;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
}

public function logIn()
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewall = 'default';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}

public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    // Create a new client to browse the application
    $this->logIn();

    // Create a new entry in the database
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/services/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /admin/services/");
    $crawler = $this->client->click($crawler->selectLink('Create a new entry')->link());

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_services[services]'  => 'Test',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $this->client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // Check data in the show view
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('td:contains("Test")')->count(), 'Missing element td:contains("Test")');

    // Edit the entity
    $crawler = $this->client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Update')->form(array(
        'artel_profilebundle_services[services]'  => 'Foo',
        // ... other fields to fill
    ));

    $this->client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // Check the element contains an attribute with value equals "Foo"
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('[value="Foo"]')->count(), 'Missing element [value="Foo"]');

    // Delete the entity
    $this->client->submit($crawler->selectButton('Delete')->form());
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

    // this is line 73
    $this->assertNotRegExp('/Foo/', $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

}

in this step I have error

```
$this->assertNotRegExp('/Foo/', $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

after deleted test service function assertNotRegExp try to find in content but error something with regular I dint know. After test I have all html my page /admin/services/ and error

```
' does not match PCRE pattern "/Foo/".

    /home/ivan/host/test/src/Artel/AdminBundle/Tests/Controller/ServicesControllerTest.php:73
```

where error ?

Comment: submit done - when I get /admin/services have list service with link'Create a new entry' . And edit and create and deleted.

Comment: And which status code you get after hit submit and the page is reloaded ?

Comment: In chrome in developer tools in network I not see this http, but in postman if get have Status 200 OK
Time 1317 ms

Comment: when app/console router:debug have:
  services                                       GET             ANY    ANY  /admin/services/

Comment: In this action have not form

Comment: in rout "services" have not form only list action

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood. You are simply doing a click in your test, it's normal you get a 302.

Comment: no. I update my question

Comment: How to create client ($client = static::createClient();) with ROLE_ADMIN ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your request authenticated.

Add the following code to your test class :

```
private $client = null;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
}
private function logIn()
{
    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewall = 'secured_area';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

And use it in your test method before create the client:

```
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    $this->logIn();
    // Do your logic
}
```

See [Simulate authentication in test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html)

Comment: $this->client , what is it ?

Comment: I try $this->createClient()

Comment: See changes in my answer (also you can find all in the documentation)

Comment: Remove the trailing slash at end of your url.

Comment: update. function login need return or if in testCompleteScenario I use $this->client this is no difference ? And I still have error

Comment: but still have ' does not match PCRE pattern "/Foo/".

/home/ivan/host/test/src/Artel/AdminBundle/Tests/Controller/ServicesControllerTest.php:51

Comment: See the phpunit documentation https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#idp2093424 . You are asking many different things

Comment: I read and find assertNotRegExp and I do it like documentation, but something wrong (

Comment: I dont understand why need assertNotRegExp, besause this test return failer and this is ok because in my content not strinf Foo. So I use assertRegExp this assert not find Foo and return ok